# Send a Message Dialog to a another user

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

In my activity a user is shown another user based around various criteria. I am trying to figure out a way to alert that the other user that this individual has selected him upon the current user button click. I am thinking that once the user has click on the confirm button, an alert dialog message would be displayed to the user so that he is aware that someone has click confirm on him.

I am using Parse to manage the users, and the below is the code that would display a user based around various criteria.

```
query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
                // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                query1.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().
                    getObjectId());

                Button buttonconfirm = (Button) getView().
                    findViewById(R.id.btnMatchConfirm);
                buttonconfirm.setText("Confirm");

                mUserNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().
                    findViewById(R.id.userlistname);

                mUserNameRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Name").toString()); 


                Button newPage = (Button)getView().
                    findViewById(R.id.btnMatchConfirm);
                newPage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                newPage.setText("Confirm");
                newPage.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);

                newPage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")); 
                newPage.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = newPage.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

                newPage.setLayoutParams(params);

                newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                  //    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                  //    currentUser.put("UserMatchName", mUserRetrieved);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
                            OptionActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });                
            }
        } else if (e != null) {       

        }
    }
});
```

I am not sure where to go from here, and any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you already using Parse, you should use their Push notifications. Register receivers with a channel for each user.
When a user selects another, notify your parse back-end and then from the back-end send push filtered by the selected channel.

See more :
https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#push

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I was skeptical about using Push because I initially thought that it only updates the user through the notification, and not send messages within the app.

Comment: You register a receiver and then you decide how to deal with it, you can display a notification or you can just do whatever you want